# trying to understand keras's tokenizer texts_to_sequences

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am using:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

max_words = 10000

text = 'Decreased glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase activity along with oxidative stress affects visual contrast sensitivity in alcoholics.'

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)

print(sequences)
```

This results in this:

```
[[8], [2], [7], [12], [2], [5], [1], [2], [8], [], [14], [9], [16], [7], [6], [1], [2], [], [19], [], [17], [10], [6], [1], [17], [10], [5], [3], [2], [], [8], [2], [10], [15], [8], [12], [6], [14], [2], [11], [5], [1], [2], [], [5], [7], [3], [4], [13], [4], [3], [15], [], [5], [9], [6], [11], [14], [], [20], [4], [3], [10], [], [6], [21], [4], [8], [5], [3], [4], [13], [2], [], [1], [3], [12], [2], [1], [1], [], [5], [18], [18], [2], [7], [3], [1], [], [13], [4], [1], [16], [5], [9], [], [7], [6], [11], [3], [12], [5], [1], [3], [], [1], [2], [11], [1], [4], [3], [4], [13], [4], [3], [15], [], [4], [11], [], [5], [9], [7], [6], [10], [6], [9], [4], [7], [1], []]
```

What does this actually mean? Why are there so many entries? I can see that there are 16 words as `Keras` splits the above text like so:

```
{'oxidative', 'contrast', '6', 'affects', 'in', 'dehydrogenase', 'visual', 'stress', 'glucose', 'phosphate', 'along', 'activity', 'with', 'alcoholics', 'decreased', 'sensitivity'}
```

This by the way is kind of wrong for my scenario, as I would like to prevent the split of `glucose-6-phosphate` but I think I can prevent this using:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tokenizer.fit_on_texts` expects a list of texts, where you are passing it a single string. Likewise for `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences()`. Try passing lists to both methods:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

max_words = 10000

text = 'Decreased glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase ...'

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
```

This will give you a list of integer sequences encoding the words in your sentence, which is probably your use case:

```
sequences

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the `Tokenizer` has build the dictionary of characters instead of words. The dictionary will look like this:

```
{'s': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 3, 'i': 4, 'a': 5, 'o': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 8, 'l': 9, 'h': 10, 'n': 11, 'r': 12, 'v': 13, 'g': 14, 'y': 15, 'u': 16, 'p': 17, 'f': 18, '6': 19, 'w': 20, 'x': 21}
```

`Tokenizer` takes a list as input not a string. Do this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
max_words = 10000

text = 'Decreased glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase activity along with oxidative stress affects visual contrast sensitivity in alcoholics.'
text = text_to_word_sequence(text)
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
print(sequences)
```

This is how your dictionary will look like now:

```
print(tokenizer.word_index)

{'decreased': 1, 'glucose': 2, '6': 3, 'phosphate': 4, 'dehydrogenase': 5, 'activity': 6, 'along': 7, 'with': 8, 'oxidative': 9, 'stress': 10, 'affects': 11, 'visual': 12, 'contrast': 13, 'sensitivity': 14, 'in': 15, 'alcoholics': 16}
```

Comment: How do we obtain the dictionary from the Tokenizer?

Comment: Just call `tokenizer.word_index`. By dictionary, I'm assuming, you mean `word_to_index` mapping.